# Magento2: Overwriting block file showing ReferenceError: opConfig is not defined

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I want to overwrite this block file **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php**

But I am getting ReferenceError: opConfig is not defined error while changing or selecting the custom option.

See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code ?

Comment: Have you override any js file ?

Comment: No, not overriding any js files

Comment: I have just taken this function getValuesHtml() in our block file. @KeyurShah